# Driving P-Channel MOSFET with switch to Ground

Tags: power, mosfet

My understanding of working with P-Channel MOSFET's gave me this basic schematic which I'm sure is missing a few things here and there.

My load side will be connected to a complex load with a boost converter, microcontroller, IC's
and a bunch of other things, so I'm using a P-Channel to ensure I have a valid reference
to ground. The LED and resistor in here are just for reference. The actual load is likely sensitive to ground-shifts [AT90 MCU], otherwise I'd much rather use an N-Channel.

I am planning on using a toggle switch to turn the whole circuit On and Off, but the switch I want is not rated for enough current unfortunately [I need it to be quite small]. Thus, instead of putting it in-line, I'm using it to "drive" a MOSFET instead. My goal is for the entire load side to be off when the switch is one way and on when the other.

Will this super simple circuit accomplish the job or am I missing some current limiting resistors somewhere along the way? *Note that MOSFET part number is just arbitrary. I'm going to be looking for one with a much lower gate threshold voltage instead.*

[image]

Comment: You will want to increase R2 to 10K to reduce wasted power

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Right! Thanks for catching that! :D

Comment: with a gazillian FETs available, sometimes its hard to find the most economical solution. e.g. https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/rohm-semiconductor/RZM001P02T2L/5042832 this works at < 3 Ohms in Fig 9 @ ~>3V well for 20mA @ $0.31 with lots in stock but I found it by searching Vgs(th)<1.5V, otherwise any PNP would work at half the price(1) or < $0.05 in volume . Schematic could be improved a bit.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 Thanks for looking into that! My load's actually going to be fairly power hungry @ 500mA at least. I'm looking at the ZXMP6A17GQTA P-FET w/ a Vgs(th) of 1V @ 250µA. Around $0.75 on Digikey and $0.55 on LCSC unfortunately, so that's not great.

Comment: THanks for sharing important specs that ought to be in your question. These are better and under 6 cents at digikey (10k) https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/diodes-incorporated/DMG2301L-13/5768496

Comment: MOSFETs can't be relied upon for going open-circuit to more than a few 100 kohms so, if your load is sometimes "light" you may not adequately turn off the load.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm a little confused as to what you mean unfortunately. Do MOSFETs have a hard time actually switching an entire downstream load circuit like this? If so, is there an alternative part that you recommend or a whole different switching circuit entirely?

Comment: I don't make recommendations on insufficient information.